# "noob" considered slang? offensive?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, slang

I came across this word recently:

> noob

I found out that it means

> a newbie or inexperienced.

What I also found out is that some websites have been referring to this word as a Internet slang. So is this word really a bit offensive? I am just curious.

Comment: I hope that you saw it defined as “[newbie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/newbie)”, not “[new](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/new) [bee](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bee)” (though it may have been originally a corruption of ”new [boy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boy)“).

Comment: oh yes "newbie" definitely! my bad! Thanx for the edits!

Comment: or maybe noob is a shortage for no-objective?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Slang is not inherently offensive. The term usually denotes non-standard linguistic innovations restricted to a particular speech community and used to mark one’s membership in that community.

Typically slang is the speech of young people—words and phrases which mark the user as ‘cool’ or ‘hip’, familiar with the currently most fashionable artistic and social trends. But every in-group has its own slang. In the grain-processing industry, for example, warehouse receipts and shipping certificates are both referred to colloquially as ‘tickets’.

Slang should be distinguished from *jargon*, which is the **formal** usages or terms of art peculiar to a particular professional group.

*Noob* or *n00b* (formed after *boob*, in the sense ‘stupid and unsophisticated person’) was coined in the direct-dial bulletin-board communities which preceded internet forums. As SF. says, it is deliberately derogatory, employed to distinguish novice participants from the established  senior users, masters of the medium. But it was  balanced by a corresponding non-derogatory slang term, *l337* (= *leet*, ‘elite’), for the established users.

Comment: Gr8 answer! Wish I could give you +50 for this one. From @SF's answer i was a bit confused between "slang and derogatory" and "insulting" if used against seasoned players, although i did make out that it is a slang! Thank you both!

Comment: @abhatt Note that sometimes, people will refer to themselves as a "noob". For example, "Can you guys help me. I'm a noob at Javascript?" In this example, it isn't really being used as an insult, but instead just admitting they are new at something. It is generally much less harsh when used like that. It can be used in the same way against oneself though... for example, if a player in a game makes an obvious mistake, they may admit "I was a noob there." It is a subtle difference.

Comment: @Gray..yes got it! Can you give me an example or a sentence wherein it has been used as an offensive term?

Comment: Often times, in team games, immature players will say something like "I hate having all these noobs on my team" to express their frustration when they are losing. Another example, with the singular "noob", would be: A player makes a mistake, then someone would type in chat or say over the microphone "Wow, what a noob" or "Uninstall [the game] noob." Often times, these "thoughts" are expressed with many expletives and use poor/lazy English. You generally don't want to emulate these people, they tend to be toxic and make games less fun for everyone. Let me know if that cleared things up.

Comment: @abhatt - _"Stupid noob doesn't even know how to do that."_ That would be offensive. It always, always, ALWAYS depends on context. Even a noob knows that :^)

Comment: Almost any word can run the range from gross insult to neutral description to affectionate to praise, depending on how it is used. If you're screaming it at someone while you berate him for a mistake, it's an insult. The very same word said while patting someone on the back and telling all present that he's your best friend would have a very different meaning. And some words -- like "noob" -- are neutral enough that they easily run this gamut. "You f---in noob, you deleted all my files!" is surely an insult. "Would you help Bob out? He's a noob here" is pretty neutral.

Comment: I saw *newbie* for years before *noob*, and I still see *newb* sometimes.  This seems like a more likely origin to me than *boob*.

Comment: I think it's worth making the distinction between *noob* and *newb*. This may not be the case in everyone's experience or in all situations/groups of people, but there is definitely a difference between the two for at least some people (of which I am one!). Newb means simply that you are new to something, and has no negative implications. It is not at all offensive. Noob sometimes means that you are new to something (but not always) and carries the implication that you are stupid/inept and not good at the task. It is definitely offensive. Not everyone observes this difference, but it exists.

Comment: @snailboat Yes, *newbie* was around before *noob* - it appears to have arisen in the Vietnam-era military - but its recasting as *noob* in the 80s was clearly (at least to me at the time) intended sarcastically analogical with *boob*.

Answer (score 6):

It's slang and derogatory. The non-slang, milder version is "newbie".

"Noob" doesn't have to be applied to a player who's new to a game - but to one who makes newcomer's mistakes. Choosing tactics that is known to fail, failure to secure essential resources, generally failing stupid mistakes any experienced player knows not to make is known as "noob mistakes" and anyone who makes them, earns the moniker of "noob". Of course assigning this name to a seasoned player will be seen as quite insulting, especially if they didn't make any of these mistakes.